# VB.NET add an element to the XML document with LINQ to XML

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I'm adding an element to existing XML doc with the following code:

```
        Dim theXMLSource As String = Server.MapPath("~/Demo/") & "LabDemo.xml"
    Dim nodeElement As XElement

    Dim attrAndValue As XElement = _
        <LabService>
            <ServiceType>
                <%= txtServiceType.Text.Trim %>
            </ServiceType>
            <Level>
                <%= txtLevel.Text.Trim %>
            </Level>
        </LabService>

    nodeElement.Add(New XElement(attrAndValue))
    nodeElement.Save(theXMLSource)
```

It makes error like this:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Error line: nodeElement.Add(New XElement(attrAndValue))
```

I debugged it but I couldn't get the error yet. Can you show what the problem is? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the existing file, like this:

```
Dim theXMLSource As String = Server.MapPath("~/Demo/LabDemo.xml")
Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load(theXMLSource)

...

document.Root.Add(attrAndValue)
document.Save(theXMLSource)
```

Answer (score 0):

You define nodeElement but then do not instantiate it before you call its methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate first:

```
Dim nodeElement As New XElement
```

Answer (score 0):

"Dim nodeElement As New XElement"

Actually New is not a valid method for XElements. Even if it passes the debug (which I doubt it) it will result in an unhandled overload

Like SLaks said, you can open the existing file - (I reckon the file probably exists like you said in the post).

You can either use

```
document.Root.Add(attrAndValue)
```

or

```
Dim nodeElement As XElement = document.<theXMLroot>(0)

nodeElement.Add(attrAndValue)
```

followed by

```
document.Save(theXMLSource)
```

both work the same way. since you're using literals, I thought you might want to know the "second way" It's useful mainly because you can change  to the  where you want to insert the element.

for instance

```
Dim nodeElement As XElement = document.<theXMLroot>.<parent>(0)
```

or

```
Dim nodeElement As XElement = document...<parent>(0)
```

hope it helps